# How to do a sprintf on a uint32_t hexidecimal to and store it into a string?

Tags: c, printf

I am running a timer to calculate the efficiency of my program and I need to output it to a hyperterminal.
So, I need to do a `sprintf` on a `uint32_t` hexidecimal to store it into a string.
But I keep getting an error on the `%08X`. So what should I use instead? 
I have tried using `%ll`, `%lu` but the warning is still there.

```
volatile char str_cycles=0;
volatile uint32_t total_cycles = 0x00ffffff - current_time;
sprintf(str_cycles, "%08X",total_cycles);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It's always a good idea to quote the exact error message.

Comment: What does your error message tell you? Read it and try to understand it. If you don't, you can ask here.

Answer (score 4):

You should be getting an error because `str_cycles` is shown as `volatile char str_cycles;` (a single character).

You should be using `<inttypes.h>` and:

```
char str_cycles[16];

snprintf(str_cycles, sizeof(str_cycles), "%08" PRIX32, total_cycles);
```

Generally, `snprintf()` should be preferred over `sprintf()`, but if you have enough space allocated it is perfectly OK to use `sprintf()`.

I'm not convinced about the `volatile` qualifier either; it is your job to determine why you have that and whether it is correct and whether it matters.  Generally, you do not want a volatile string; it makes using it unreliable. (This answer first omitted the `volatile` on `str_cycles`, then added it, and has now omitted it again.)

Answer (score 1):

Use fixed width print specifiers.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
char buf[9];
sprintf(buf, "%08" PRIX32,total_cycles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to an `int` or `unsigned` first. This is the type expected by `%X`:

```
sprintf(str_cycles, "%08X", (unsigned) total_cycles);
```

Comment: `total_cycles` **is** declared `uint32_t` which I consider `unsigned`.

Comment: `unsigned` is not guaranteed to be the same as `uint32_t`.

Comment: @alk, you consider it `unsigned` but perhaps the compiler doesn't?

Comment: `unsigned` is only guaranteed to have the range 0 - 65535.  With this approach, suggest `sprintf(str_cycles, "%08lX", (unsigned long) total_cycles);`

Comment: @chux that works. I think I like your answer best though, use the fixed-width specifiers in `inttypes.h`. Are those part of a standard or just common conventions?

Comment: Uhm, ya, yes .. my wording was inaccurate I meant "not signed".

Comment: The macros for format specifiers like PRIX32 are in the C99 and C11 spec.  I'm confident they are not in C89.